# C++ Copying Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, chess

Hi i would like to know how i could copy the contents of a 2d Array pointer in C++ to another location and set another pointer to it so that when i make changes on the copied pointer nothing happens to the original data?

Basically its an array pointer to pieces on a chessboard. so it goes like `Piece * oldpointer = board[8][8]`. now i want to copy all the contents in this pointer including methods like `getvalue(), getcolor()` etc which are in the Pieces header file to another location and set a pointer to it so i can do operations there and test it without it having to affect this orginal data? I read somewhere i had to use `allocate()` but im not sure. please help

Comment: A solution is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/4810676#4810676), look under "Conversions" (about 3 pages down).

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you could define 2D array type as follows (you need modern C++ compiler):

```
#include <array>
typedef std::array<std::array<Piece, 8>, 8> board_t;
```

If your compiler doesn't support `std::array` you can use [`boost::array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/array.html) instead:

```
#include <boost/array.hpp>
typedef boost::array<boost::array<Piece, 8>, 8> board_t;
```

Now you can use the type above. As I can see you need to copy the object to which the pointer points:

```
board_t* oldpointer = new board_t;

// do some with oldpointer

// now make a copy of the instance of the object oldpointer points to
// using copy-constructor
board_t* newpointer = new board_t( *oldpointer );
// now newpointer points to the newly created independent copy

// do more

// clean up
delete oldpointer;

// do more with newpointer

// clean up
delete newpointer;
```

Comment: There's also std::vector, which is supported everywhere.

Comment: `std::vector` allocates memory dynamically. In chess there's fixed size of the board as I know, so no need in `std::vector`.

Comment: You're right, but given that the OP is clearly a novice, pointing him towards high-level or newly-introduced libraries like Boost or TR1 may not be the best way for him to learn. I suspect a vector would be more than sufficient for his purposes and it's documented well and available everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using C++, why not define a copy constructor for your Piece class? Then just

```
Piece copied_piece(*board[8][8]);
```

If your class is POD, you should even be able to get by with the default copy constructor.

Comment: Although the board is what he wants to copy... 8-)
Assuming you have a board class that has the 8x8 pieces, then you can do something like this: Board a; ... Board b(a); The array should be hidden inside the board and all accesses done with a Piece get(int x, int y);.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy by allocating memory at the destination and then memcopy

```
dest_pointer = (<<my type>>*) malloc(sizeof(<<my type>>);
memcpy(dest_pointer, src_pointer, sizeof(<<my type>>);
```

Btw, the methods are never copied. they don't belong to an object.

Comment: Don't forget to include <cstdlib>.